# IBOutlet seems to be nil when called on app delegate's didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken

Tags: ios, swift, webview

Using latest version of XCode and Swift.

I have created a simple application with a webview. The IBOutlet within the controller is wired up correctly. When loading a request inside viewDidLoad() everything seems to alright.

However, I wanted to pass over the device token to the webview. I am using the following function inside AppDelegate:

```
var vc = ViewController()
...
func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {
    var token = NSString(format: "%@", deviceToken)
    token = token.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString( "<", withString: "")
    token = token.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString( ">", withString: "")
    token = token.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "")
    vc.deviceToken = token as String;
    vc.loadSomeUrl()
}
```

The loadSomeUrl() function looks like this:

```
func loadSomeUrl() {
    let url = NSURL (string: "http://google.de" );
    let requestObj = NSURLRequest(URL: url!);

    webview.loadRequest(requestObj);

}
```

When running the application, I am getting the following message:

`fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

I have literally no idea what the issue is. I found out that the webview is suddenly nil, although viewDidLoad() has been called before. I added a print(webview) to viewDidLoad() which worked correctly. When adding print(webview) to loadSomeUrl(); the above fatal error is triggered as well.

For further investigation I added the following snippet to the outlet.

```
 @IBOutlet var webview: UIWebView!{
    didSet {
        print("webview set to %@", webview);
    }
}
```

The outut is just fine. The above error occurs after that output.

`webview set to %@ <UIWebView: 0x145d18910; frame = (0 0; 600 556); autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x145d20f20>>
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

Does anybody has a clue what the issue is? Maybe I am adressing this whole problem the wrong way.

Comment: requestObj is not nil, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the in AppDelegate you are creating anew instance of your VC, and there the webView is nil.

```
var vc = ViewController()
```

So you need to load the ViewController in the AppDelegate from the storyboard.

Another way is to send a notification to viewController when you receive a token.

In obj-c it's:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"tokenNotification" object:token userInfo:userInfo];
```

Swift:

```
//AppDElegate

func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData)
    {
        var token = NSString(format: "%@", deviceToken)
        token = token.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString( "<", withString: "")
        token = token.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString( ">", withString: "")
        token = token.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "")

        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("tokenNotification", object: token);

    }

// VC
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ViewController.loadSomeUrl), name: "tokenNotification", object: nil)

    }

func loadSomeUrl(notification:NSNotification) {
        let url = NSURL (string: "http://google.de" );
        let requestObj = NSURLRequest(URL: url!);

        webview.loadRequest(requestObj);

    }
```

Comment: That's exactly the code I am using in my AppDelegate. How do I access the controller from the storyboard in Swift? Thanks a lot!

Comment: edited my answer, please take a look at the notification use